# Displaying a message as a popup/alert in Django?

Tags: python, html, django, popup, alert

I have a form that, upon submission it just redirects to itself again. I'm trying to display a message that says "You have entered (work_area)." Currently, I only got the displaying part without the variable in it, but it shows within the html after the user submits it. I would like it to be a popup or alert message that the user can close after they see it, but I don't understand how this would work in Django.

**views.py**

```
class EnterExitArea(CreateView):
    model = EmployeeWorkAreaLog
    template_name = "operations/enter_exit_area.html"
    form_class = WarehouseForm
    #success_message = "You have logged into %(work_area)s"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        emp_num = form.cleaned_data['employee_number']
        area = form.cleaned_data['work_area']
        station = form.cleaned_data['station_number']

        if 'enter_area' in self.request.POST:
            form.save()
            EmployeeWorkAreaLog.objects.filter((Q(employee_number=emp_num) & Q(work_area=area) & Q(station_number=station)).update(time_in=datetime.now())

            messages.info(self.request, "You have entered")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info)
```

**enter_exit_area.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block main %}
    <form id="warehouseForm" action="" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" novalidate >
        {% csrf_token %}

        {% if messages %}
            <ul class="messages">
            {% for message in messages %}
                <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}

        <div>
            <div>
                <label>Employee</label>
                {{ form.employee_number }}
            </div>

            <div>
                <label>Work Area</label>
                {{ form.work_area }}
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Station</label>
                {{ form.station_number }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit" name="enter_area" value="Enter">Enter Area</button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

{% endblock main %}
```

And it displays like this:

[image]

Edit:

[image]

Comment: You might want to look into jQuery dialog or bootstrap modal or just a plain vanilla Javascript alert.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is more a **javascript** question but anyways, this is how I handle this (if you are using **bootstrap**):

1) Create a `message.html` file with the following content:

```
{% for message in messages %}
  <div class="toast notification bg-{% if message.tags == 'error' %}danger{% else %}{{message.tags}}{% endif %}" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" data-delay="5000">
    <div class="toast-header">
      <strong class="mr-auto">
        {% if message.tags == 'error' %}
          <i class="fas fa-times mr-2"></i>
        {% elif message.tags == 'warning' %}
          <i class="fas fa-exclamation mr-2"></i>
        {% elif message.tags == 'info' %}
          <i class="fas fa-info mr-2"></i>
        {% elif message.tags == 'success' %}
          <i class="fas fa-check mr-2"></i>
        {% endif %}
        {{message.tags|capfirst}}
      </strong>
      <button type="button" class="ml-2 mb-1 close" data-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="toast-body">
      {{message|safe}}
    </div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

2) Change your `base.html` and add:

```
...
{% include 'message.html' %}
...


<!-- and at the end:-->
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
{% if messages %}
  <script>
      {% for message in messages %}
          $(document).ready(function () {
              $('.toast').toast('show');
          });
      {% endfor %}
  </script>
{% endif %}
```

Also, don't forget to include bootstrap.

This way you can use django messages on *all* of your templates, without explicitly change them.

#### Edit

You also need this custom css class in order for your notification to show on top right of the page:

```css
.notification{
    position: absolute;
    top: 5rem;
    right: 1rem;
}
```

Comment: This did the trick pretty well, I think I might have just done something weird. Two questions, do I add the script inside the <body> tags in base.html? and, I get this warning that says `unresolved function or method toast()` for `$('.toast').toast('show');`. I'm adding a picture of how it's showing on the page right now.

Comment: 1) Yes, put the script inside the `body` tag - at the end. 2) I think you are missing bootstrap's `javascript` file (`bootstrap.min.js`).

Comment: It is included in base.html as `<script src="{% static "js/plugins/bootstrap.min.js" %}"></script>` but it still renders like the image I added to my original post

Comment: I have scripts in this order and it's working fine for me: 1)jQuery 2)bootstrap 3)the custom script. Maybe you are adding the custom script before the bootstrap or jQuery?

Comment: Hmmm, I have the `<script src="{% static "js/plugins/jquery.js" %}"></script>` and the bootstrap ones I added above within the <head> tags and then your script at the end, inside the <body> and according to Network they both loaded successfully

Comment: Check the edit to see if it solves the problem (sorry, I forgot about that custom css class)?

Comment: You do not need   `{% for message in messages %}` since you only need to call
              `$('.toast').toast('show');` once  (indeed, it does not use the `message` variable)

Answer (score 0):

Django has built-in functions for that which is messages.

```
messages.success(self.request,"message sent")
```

In your HTML, make sure to create a message class.

```
{% if message.tags %} class="{{message.tags}}"{% endif %}
```